# How i add new link after Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View in quick edit section

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-admin, wp-list-table

I want to add new link in custom post type . I have create a custom post type and i want to add new link after `Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View` links like `Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View | PDF` . How i add in custom post . i wondered many places but not getting any proper result for  add new custom link after `Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View`. Please let me know how i add.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it by creating a hook for `post_row_actions` filter. If your CPT is hierarchical post type use `page_row_actions` filter.

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'wpse8170_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function wpse8170_row_actions( $actions, WP_Post $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'my-custom-post-type' ) {
        return $actions;
    }

    $actions['wpse8170-pdf'] = '<a href="http://your/url/here">PDF</a>';
    return $actions;
}
```